# Social Login in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, facebook-login, google-signin

How can I implement Login with Facebook & Login with Google in Xamarin forms using native code for Android & iOS?

I don't want to use a plugin. I want to use dependency service to implement native code in both Android & iOS in Xamarin Forms Project.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a pretty open question but you basically need to (atleast for the google login use firebase ):

1. Setup a new project in firebase with Authentication
2. Add nuget Xamarin.firebase.iOS.auth to your iOS project and xamarin.firebase.auth to your android project
3. create an interface in your shared code call it `IFirebaseAuthentication`
4. Implement the interface on each platform
5. Use your auth module with `DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthentication>();` from the shared code

You will find more details on step 1 and 4 here
https://www.lindseybroos.be/2020/03/xamarin-forms-and-firebase-authentication/

Happy coding

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to make user Login using Google & Facebook (Not using email). Can I do this using the mentioned packages?

Comment: You can use this approach to sign in using google (gmail). Facebook requires a different approach. You should probably split up your question into two; one for each sign in approach.