# Xamarin.Forms Firebase Authentication With Google

Tags: firebase, authentication, xamarin

I've successfully implemented the Firebase Auth with Email and Password, but I'm getting a hard time implementing the Authentication with Google, Facebook, or Twitter.

I've searched for days and couldn't find a single hint on how to do this in Xamarin Forms.

Any help is appreciated.

I'm using the NuGet `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth`

Comment: This is a pretty broad question,you can refer to this similar thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71233000/social-login-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I've seen this question and the link provided, but it only helps with the email/password, no insight of how to do it with Google or any other authentication method. Thanks anyway.